# Slicing timestamp from date object in EJS - Javascript, HTML, Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I'm currently working on looping through and displaying some objects on an EJS webpage. I'm looping through all of them fine and displaying all other data, but I am unable to trim the timestamp off of a date attribute I'm trying to display. It will display the whole date without trimming, but when I try to alter the string, nothing displays. Here is the code for that part of the EJS file:

```
<h1 align = "center"><span class="fa fa-map"></span> View Community Maps</h1><br>
<p align="center">Click on a Community Map below to view the full map.</p><br>

<% for (var i=0; i < Maps.length; i++) { %>
    <a href="/viewMap/<%= Maps[i].mapID %>" style="text-decoration: none; color: #333333">
        <div class="well" align="center">
        <script>
            var date = Maps[i].mapDate;
            var dateStringNoTime = date.slice(0, 10); //where I'm trying to slice the timestamp
        </script>

            <h3>Community Map for Floor <%= Maps[i].floorLevel%></h3>
            <p><%=Employee.firstName%> <%=Employee.lastName%></p>
            <p>Week of <script>dateStringNoTime</script></p> // WILL NOT DISPLAY. Displays as "Week of"
        </div>
    </a>
<% } %>
```

Any help or tips would be appreciated. Thanks! :)

Comment: You can use maps[i].mapdate.getDate() ejs supports some date methods dont need slice

Comment: @ŞükranEken `<%= Maps[i].mapDate.getDate()%>` prints out "2". Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this Maps[i].mapDate.getDate()+"."+Maps[i].mapDate.getMonth()+"."+Maps[i].mapDate.getFullYear() but if your month=1, you get 0 ;but you can do this